# Error Building Project using Spring Security Tutorial

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Am using JDK 1.8 and Spring Boot 1.2.0 RELEASE.

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sampleapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <name>Spring Boot Security Example</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQLDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My main app:

```
package com.sampleapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

My SecurityConfig file:

```
package com.sampleapp.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration                  
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

     @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

There's other classes and interfaces in my sample app but I wanted to keep this post as simple and straightfoward as possible.

When I run this using:

mvn spring-boot:run

Receive the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans. factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.sampleapp.config.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.sampleapp.config.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
    ... 76 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.751 s
```

What am I possibly doing wrong? I checked out this code from:

http://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/

The only thing I changed was the name of the app to sampleapp along with some packages (namespaces)...

His code works but I wonder why mine doesn't?

*EDITED* ( for David Hernandez's question):

David, thanks for commenting, I am not sure if I understand your question because the SecurityConfig file uses the org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService from Spring... In the code that I copied, there is a CurrentUserDetailsService that implements UserDetailService from Spring. If this was your question, here's the code:

```
package com.sampleapp.service.currentuser;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.sampleapp.domain.CurrentUser;
import com.sampleapp.domain.User;
import com.sampleapp.service.user.UserService;

public class CurrentUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrentUserDetailsService.class);

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public CurrentUserDetailsService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOG.debug("Authenticating user with email={}", email.replaceFirst("@.*", "@***"));
        User user = userService.getUserByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User with email=%s was not found", email)));
        return new CurrentUser(user);
    }
}
```

Happy programming!

Comment: Can you post your `UserDetailsService` implementation? It is complaining about not having it correctly inject through `Autowired`.

Comment: David, thank you - I edited  my post in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you Application.java is in the root of the project
If you refactored the packages
you should have something like that

```
com
-sampleapp
--other packages
Application.java
```

By default spring boot use @ComponentScan and scan at the root of the project

If you have something outside your com.sampleapp the @ComponeScan won't be able to see it

You can add your @ComponentScan with your base packages

Ex.

```
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"package containing UserDetailsService", "packages containing your app"} )
```

In your case the ComponentScan is not finding the components so I think it is scanning in the wrong place

Comment: Filippo - thank you for your suggestion but it broke my code. It now has a FileNotFoundException. Where (what file) do I put @ComponentScan ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working... I was missing @Service for my Service classes.